# Why did ECMAScript 5 add .bind()?

Tags: javascript, call, bind, ecmascript-5

I just finished reading an article about ECMAScript 5 strict mode.

It says that ECMAScript 5 added .bind().

```
var obj = {
  method: function(name){
    this.name = name;
  }
};

obj.method.bind(obj,"hello");
```

Isn't it identical to **obj.method.call(obj,"hello")** ??

Comment: `obj.method.bind(obj, "hello")()` would be identical.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it's not identical.

With bind you're **producing a function**, without calling anything. With `call` — as in your `obj.method.call(obj, 'hello')` — you're actually calling a method.

An "identical" expression to `obj.method.bind(obj, 'hello')` would be `function(){obj.method.call(obj, 'hello')}`. That's more cruft. And that's the cruft ES5 is trying to provide convenience for.

There are also historical reasons for introduction of `bind`; it first became popular as one of the helper methods in Prototype.js few years ago. Then made its way to other popular libraries, such as underscore.js. ES5 just followed what was already popular and in demand.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason of creating a new function out of existing one is to be able to pass it together with the object on which it will be invoked. Consider this:

```
var obj = {
  x:"Hello",
  printPropX: function() {
    alert(this.x);
  }
};

setTimeout(obj.printPropX.bind(obj), 1000); // will alert "Hello" after 1 second

setTimeout(obj.printPropX, 1000); // will fail as 'this' won't be defined inside the function body once invoked
```

Although printPropX() is a member function of object 'obj', it won't be invoked with 'this' set to 'obj', unless bound with bind().